# How do I notify fellow developers that a target function is DEPRECATED and to offer a solution?

Tags: swift, objective-c, compiler-warnings, deprecated

**Scenario:**  A cocoaPod (or any shared code/framework) has a deprecated function (in my case MD5 hash) from which I want to display a warning & solution: SHA256().

I only have access to a shared POD. I want future users to be notified that their current API (MD5) has been deprecated and hence, should use a newer API (SHA256).

How do I notify user that the following 'doOldStuff(x: Sting)' is Deprecated, an to use 'doNewStuff(x:String) instead?

[image]

I would like to display a compiler WARNING.

Answer (score 3):

##### Swift

Use `@available` like this.

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Use doNewStuff(x:) instead")
func doOldStuff(x: String) { }
```

---

##### Objective-C

```
-(void)doOldStuffWithX:(NSString *)x __attribute__((deprecated("Use doNewStuffWithX: instead")));
```

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the Objective-C equivalent?

Comment: See the **UPDATE**.